# ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in....pdf or png (no BoundingBox)

Tags: graphics, size, includegraphics

I am using Windows x64 bit , Texmaker 5.0.3 , basic miktex 2.9.6850 and when I compile this code, I mean when I run 'LaTeX':

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{revtex4-1}
%\documentclass[rmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Varie/UNI/MANO/I-semestre-2018/fraboni/esperimenti/RT/pictures/} }

\begin{document}
```

…

```
\includegraphics{apparatus.pdf}
```

I get this error both with png and pdf formati file:

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in C:/Varie/UNI/MANO/I-semestre
-2018/fraboni/esperimenti/RT/pictures/apparatus.pdf (no BoundingBox).

I saw other answer here but I could not solve it.

Comment: What exactly are you running here? It sounds like you're running latex and not pdflatex. Try the latter.

Comment: I am running LaTeX

Comment: You need to run pdflatex, latex does noget support anything other than eps

Comment: @daleif I love you thank you very much. now it works

Answer (score 3):

You need to run pdflatex and not latex, latex does not support anything other than eps.

Comment: I am running pdflatex. Still I get the error: ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in sismo.jpg (no BoundingBox).

Comment: what if I am using overleaf and get the same error?